# How to unit test with an IEnumerable<dynamic>?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test a controller method that has a FromBody of IEnumerable.

In the controller method it is iterating as so:

```
public ActionResult<Customer> GetCustomer([FromBody] IEnumerable<dynamic> customerAccounts)
{
var accts = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in customerAccounts)
                {
                    accts.Add(item["AccountNumber"].Value);
                }
}
```

In the unit test I am doing the following on the setup passing the parameter:

```
        var accountParameters = new List<dynamic>();
            dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
            expando.AccountNumber = "1234";
            accountParameters.Add(expando);
```

Error returning:  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'

How can I resolve this I tried using an as IDictionary as well.

Comment: The right answer: don't use `dynamic` like this in the first place, why would you even try to do that?

Comment: I agree 100% eventually needs to be refactored it needs to be a strong typed object.

Comment: Every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies.

Comment: You set it like `expando.AccountNumber = "1234";` , but try to access it like `item["AccountNumber"]`

Comment: When I paste the 2nd snippet in my IDE, it works... ? Am I missing something?